# Bootstrap col- not responding on mobile with fixed position?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having some issues with a div not responding the way I believe it should be. 
I have this code;

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="header-form" style="border: 2px solid purple; margin: 1%;">
            <div class="row">
                <form ng-controller="GetQuery" ng-submit="submitForm()">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group label-floating">
                            <label class="control-label">Starbucks, McDonalds, etc..</label>
                            <input ng-model="form.keyword" type="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group label-floating">
                            <label class="control-label">City, State or Zip..</label>
                            <input ng-model="form.location" type="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <button type="submit" ng-click="Submit" href="#!view1" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Lets Go!</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works correctly. However all I know want to do, is fix this div that contains the form into position: fixed, so when you scroll the div continues to stay in view. However, when I had an in-line style

```
style="position: fixed;"
```

and I inspect it with a mobile view the div defaults to only using half the page. In a desktop view it works as it should.

What am I missing?

Comment: you bootstrap class instead for fixed position

Comment: I'm sorry.. could you elaborate?

Comment: check this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/ :)